# PHP - Looping A-Z To Sort Mysql Results using Dynamic Links

Tags: php, mysql, alphabetical

I have the following table in mysql:-

```
id | bandname
1  | a perfect circle
2  | aerosmith
3  | b.b king
4  | cat stevens
```

I am fetching all of the results in a single query with:-

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, bandname FROM bands ORDER BY bandname ASC");
```

On my page I have A-Z anchor links which bring up a new tab:-

```
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#0">0-9</a></li>
    <?php
        // Print a-z link
        for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
         $curletter = chr($i);
         echo '<li><a href="#'.$curletter.'" title="Band names beginning with letter '.$curletter.'" class="uppercase">'.$curletter.'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

I'm having trouble getting the bands listed under their tab. Currently my code is:-

```
    <div class="tabs-container">
    <?php
        // Print a-z tabs
        for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
         $curletter = chr($i);
    ?>
        <div class="tab-content" id="<?php echo $curletter; ?>">
            <?php
            while($bands = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                $bandname = $bands['bandname'];
                $bandid = $bands['id'];
                $bandletter = strtolower(substr($bandname , 0 , 1));
            }
            if($curletter==$bandletter) {
                echo '<a href="'.$bandid.'/" title="'.$bandname.'>'.$bandname.'</a>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

I know this is incorrect because I'm calling the while loop inside the for loop and that just doesn't seem right to me - as every iteration of the A-Z tab creation process will have to run through the while loop.

If I will be dealing with say 5,000 bands what is the best approach for this? One sql result looped multiple times, one result with each band then held in an alphabetical array, or an ajax sql query whenever a user clicks on one of the anchor links?

None of this even starts to deal with the 0-9 tab which I think will be an issue itself given my current code. Any pointers really would be appreciated.

I have searched for an answer but not found something similiar to my question :)

Comment: Although I can see better solutions for the looping problem you have (one loop should be enough), I would definitely not send 5000 results to the browser, that does not make for a very pleasant browsing experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I wouldn't recommend the method you've used at all, if you want to keep it as simple as you have then you need to extract all of the band names using the while before you enter the name looping foreach by putting them into a temporary array, or better still before any output takes place. This will allow you to use `foreach()` on this array instead of the while. You could also sort these into arrays by letter too, making it simpler to see which letters have bands that start with it

## Some extra tips:

- Use [range()](http://php.net/range) instead of the `for($i = ... )` and `chr()` for the letters listings
- Give your href values more than just the letter as the id (aesthetic but certainly better) such as `letter-a` `letter-b` and so on
- If you're using 5000+ records you should be serving these on separate pages in my opinion with pagination rather than on one large page of bands
- If these are not going to change very often, you'd be best using a caching system of some sort to keep database querying to a minimum
- If you use the array by letter method I've given above, you can use the [count()](http://php.net/count) function to add the band number counts to the letter listings (and even hiding letters you have no bands for)

Comment: Many thanks. Currently I only have 3 records but I'm planning for scaling in future ;)